# Filtering non-Typeable characters in unicode

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010

In an old application programmed under Delphi 6 (non-Unicode platform), i used to filter out non-typeable characters simply by referencing their cell numbers in the ANSI character table ( **if (aKeyChar in [#32..#254]) then....** ).

Now that i shifted into Delphi 2010 where the platform is Unicode based, those character mappings are not relevant anymore. Is there a clean way to meet this objective in Delphi 2010?

Comment: Use the [CharInSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.CharInSet) function?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "non-typeable". I'm pretty sure that ASCII characters less than 32 are typeable, if you know how. Do you mean "non-printable". Anyway, you need to define what you mean here.

Comment: @whosrdaddy `ord(aKeyChar)<32` is cleaner I think

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, totally agree, just pointing out that x in [Enum] where x is Char must now use the CharInSet function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, by "non-typeable" characters i mean backspace, delete...

Comment: You mean just those two? Or more besides.

Comment: No, all "non-typeable" or "non-printable"(as you have put it) characters. I just mentioned those two as examples.

Comment: Non-typeable makes no sense to me. It is possible to type characters with code < 32. I believe that you will need to decide which characters you are talking about. Can you list their Unicode code points?

Comment: @David Heffernan. Sorry for replying on a late notice. As i tried to elaborate above by "non-typeable" or "non-printable" characters i mean  backspace, delete, Ctrl+A...any key stroke which doesn't end up displaying a visible character in your current editor, or control. In a Delphi 6 application i could easily do this with a [if (aKeyChar in [#32..#254]) then ] condition but in a Unicode based Delphi 2010 those positions are irrelevant.

Comment: I still don't understand. I think your definition is incomplete. Anyway, never mind. I guess you know what you mean which is ultimately what matters.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the various helper functions in the [`System.Character`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Character) unit, such as [`GetUnicodeCategory()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Character.GetUnicodeCategory), [`IsControl()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Character.IsControl), [`IsLetterOrDigit()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Character.IsLetterOrDigit), [`IsWhiteSpace()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Character.IsWhiteSpace), etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Unicode, to determine if a code point is a control character (assuming that is what you meant with "typeable"), it is not good enough to see if the value is in a set. To get the "control characters", you can check with the `System.Character` class:

```
if Character.IsControl(aKeyChar) then
```

But note that you may have to check if the WideChar is a low or high surrogate too, e.g.

```
if Character.IsLowSurrogate(aKeyChar) then
  // is unprintable in and of itself and next WideChar must be a high surrogate.
  // the combination is printable.
```

Note that a surrogate pair (low surrogate + high surrogate together) can be printable again. A low surrogate alone is not printable.

Comment: Why do you say that surrogates are not printable

Comment: The first surrogate is not. So if he is checking single WideChars, and not strings, a first surrogate is not "a printable". If the first surrogate is one of two elements of a string, of course the entire pair can be printable.

Comment: UTF-16 is a variable length encoding. It makes no sense whatsoever to process it element-wise. Terminology is really important here. You use "code point" incorrectly. Two surrogate pairs combine to make up a single code point.

Comment: I amended the answer. I know that UTF-16 is a variable length encoding. A surrogate pair (low + high surrogate together) is generally printable, a low surrogate alone is not.

Comment: Your edit still gets the terminology wrong. To be clear a `WideChar` value is not a code point. When you have surrogate pairs, you need two `WideChar` values to define a code point. OK, the next edit gets it right. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have said WideChar (or element), not code point.